# Have nice vacations (or similar)

Tags: colloquial

How do you say "have nice vacations!" when ending a conversation with somebody who is going on vacations? (at work). "Schöner Urlaub"? I'm not sure, this sounds a bit cold / weird (it still has to be not too familiar as it's for colleagues, not necessarily friends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in accusative as it's an object you wish someone to have.

> Schönen Urlaub.

That's okay for colleagues. For people you know better, particles add flavour:

> (Einen) schönen Urlaub dann.

And of course, you can also use full sentences.

> Dann (habt) mal einen schönen Urlaub.
>
> Dann wünsch ich euch (noch) einen schönen Urlaub.

Comment: For people you know better, you're not adding flavour, but meaningless filling this way. For people you know better, you should add flavour by being more precise in your wish, for example: `Erholsamen Urlaub.` or `Spannenden Urlaub.` or whatever that person wants or needs from its vacation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are wishing the nice vacation onto him (I am not claiming that this is proper English), you should be using Akkusativ, just as in „Guten Tag!“, so it is

> Schönen Urlaub!

This seems to me to be ein similar to “have nice vacations”.

Comment: Right! I forgot the grammar, was too busy figuring if this is in general an appropriate thing to say... +1 I'll select the other answer though because it has some additional infos...